# Redux toolkit filter() not working when wanting to display new array at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently building a clothing shop in which you can add products to the cart, and delete each one of them as you like and it makes the cart re-render and display a new cart without that product within it.

so I've made a Slice for cart in redux. the 'addProduct' part works fine, but the 'deleteProduct' reducer which uses filter() doesn't work. (when i click my delete button nothing happens, and no changes in difference in Redux Devtools)

my slice:

```
const selectedProductsSlice = createSlice({
    name:'selectedProducts',
    initialState:{
        productList:[],
        checkoutPrice:0,
    },
    reducers: {
        addProduct:(state,{payload}) => {
            state.productList.push(payload)
            state.checkoutPrice += payload.price
        },
        deleteProduct:(state,{payload}) => {
            state.productList.filter((foundProduct) => foundProduct.id !== payload.id)
        }
}});
```

my button and handleDelete:

```
<button className="btn-delete" onClick={handleDelete(product)}>Delete</button>

  function handleDelete(p) {
    console.log(p)
    dispatch(deleteProduct(p.product))
  }
```

edit:
filter didnt work in every possible way i tried. so i changed my way and did this instead to work. but still i wonder why didnt filter() method work properly.

```
        deleteProduct: (state, { payload }) => {
            const foundIndex = state.productList.findIndex((p) => {
                return p.product.id === payload.id
            })
            state.productList.splice(foundIndex,1)
   
        }
```

Comment: The `filter()` method creates a new array rather than modifying the current one

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` operation creates a new array without changing the existing instance. Therefore you need to assign it to `state`.

```
deleteProduct: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        productList: state.productList.filter(
            foundProduct => foundProduct.id !== payload.id
        )
    };
};
```

You also need to change the way you call the `handleDelete` in the onClick handler.

```
onClick={() => handleDelete(product)}
```

Comment: now it doesnt even load the cart page due to too many re renders

Comment: the re render issue got solved but still, when i click on delete the list does not get updated and in the redux devtools the state is undefined

Comment: do you get a product logged when you click the button in `console.log(p)`?

Comment: yes. the console log works fine

Comment: can you log and check `payload.id` and `state` in the `deleteProduct`? or using redux dev tools

Comment: You need to return the new updated state. I updated the answer again!

Comment: redux devtools shows no differences in state after pushing the delete button

Answer (score 0):

Filter methods returns new array so you have to update your existing array tool. Please update your slice:

```
const selectedProductsSlice = createSlice({
        name:'selectedProducts',
        initialState:{
        productList:[],
        checkoutPrice:0,
        },
        reducers: {
        addProduct:(state,{payload}) => {
            state.productList.push(payload)
            state.checkoutPrice += payload.price
        },
        deleteProduct:(state,{payload}) => {
            state.productList=state.productList.filter((foundProduct) => foundProduct.id !== payload.id)
        }
    }});
```

Comment: still, nothing happens in redux devtools when i try to delete

Comment: Please update your code of button, in onClick pass arrow function like that
<button className="btn-delete" onClick={()=>handleDelete(product)}>Delete</button>

  function handleDelete(p) {
    console.log(p)
    dispatch(deleteProduct(p.product))
  }
and make sure that you are passing id in payload of deleteProduct

Answer (score 0):

I went through exactly same problem as you.
I solved this problem just to move my reducer to another existing reducer
Hope you to get through it.  I couldn't pass it by